# animation with delay

Tags: jquery, animation, delay

I'm having trouble to understand how the animation , delay and text at the same time
There is a box, and inside of box said "sports", and when click on the text  where it said

test

somewhere not inside of box, but outside of box.

Once clicked, what I want move box to the left using animation, and once done animation then change  text inside of box to "basketball" from "sports" after finish move box to left.

i wrote that code here  and it does not working using delay!

```
<div id="apDiv12"><h1 id="toptitle">sports</h1>​</div>
```

---

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("p").click(function() {
 $('#apDiv12').animate({left:"200px"},3000).delay(1000);
 $('#toptitle:contains("Profil")').text("basketball");

});

});
```

please help thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`.delay` only works with the same animation queue.  The `text` change is not part of the same queue.  You probably want to use the callback function of the `.animate` method, as in:

```
.animate({left: "200px"}, 3000, function () { $("#toptitle" ...
```

See [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) for more details.

You could also use `setTimeout`.